# Is ARB_texture_storage core profile?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, texture-mapping

I am currently working on an ogl 4.3 project,I am using core profile and ARB_texture_storage is not supported albeit being in 4.2 compat. Is this  bug in SDL/my driver or is ARB_texture_storage not in core ?

Comment: Although I have answered your question, I have the suspicion that you are just asking the wrong question. Are you, by any chance, using GLEW to load the extension pointers? If so, you are just experiencing a well-known GLEW bug.

Comment: Yes I am! I was not aware of that,  is there workaround?

Comment: GLEW's extension loading is broking in core profiles. YOu can set `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;` befroe calling `glewInit()` as a workaround. The function pointer will then be loaded, but GLEW will still think that the extension is missing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't care about the extension if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality of `ARB_texture_storage` is a core feature since OpenGL 4.2, both in compatibility and core profiles. However, as this is a core feature, there is no requirement that the implementation advertises this also as any existension. In GL >=4.2, the `glTexStorage*()` familiy of functions is available and can be used, no matter if `ARB_texture_storage` is in the extension string or not.

Comment: So glTexStorage*()  being null is a bug in my case ?

Comment: @gan_: see the comment to your question.

Answer (score 3):

No, support for [`GL_ARB_texture_storage`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_storage.txt) is not technically required.

That is an extension, and the functionality provided by it is ***core*** in OpenGL 4.2+. Also do not confuse the phrase "suchandsuch is core in ..." with a core profile, they are two separate things.

Whether that extension is listed in your extension string or not, you are guaranteed all of the functionality it provides because OpenGL 4.2 requires it. In fact, the only time you would check for this extension by name is if you were running on an OpenGL 4.1 or older context.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't knew that. Probably because glew makes no differences between extentions and core stuffs.